# Import Stripe Payments/Transactions from one Stripe account into another (migrate/copy/import)

Tags: api, import, transactions, stripe-payments, migrate

We need to copy everything in one stripe account into another.

Stripe's migration team/tools [only support](https://support.stripe.com/questions/data-that-can-be-imported-to-a-stripe-account) copying of 'Customer' and 'PayMethods'.
I've found a [script to copy other stripe models](https://github.com/teamrevin/stripe-account-migration/tree/main/src/commands) but can't work out how to copy the Transaction/Payment data across.

Is this possible? Assuming I've worked out an export, is there a way to import transactions from one stipe account into a newly create stripe account?

Comment: it's not possible to import / copy transaction data from one Stripe account to another. Also see https://support.stripe.com/questions/copy-existing-account-data-to-a-new-stripe-account